# Calculating area within feature

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I have a vector layer containing 12 features, 12 areas.
Also, I have a layer containing lots of features, but I'd like to merge their values together, so I made a raster out of it. Maybe there is another way to merge them without having to rasterize them and not loosing features.

What I'd like to do is calculating the area of the second layer within each of the 12 regions. I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Does this help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/426767/88814

Comment: Run `intersect`, calculate your areas, tada.

Comment: Or this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/414975/88814

Comment: running intersection over geoprocessing gives me unusable values, not sure why it doesn't turn out right.

Comment: Please provide example data, or at least images.